# Php paypalewp on windows not working right, short return

Tags: php, paypal, openssl

I am working on a payment script using paypalewp, it seems to work fine in the stage environment which is a centos linux box, however on my dev box it doesn't...

when I run the button creation script on my local machine (windows vista ultimate) the button generated code looks like this

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
```

however on the linux box it's like this...

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
```

It uses the same code, parameters, and ssl keys. The one on stage works fine when connecting to paypal, the one on my local box doesn't. There is something wrong with the configurations, any thoughts?

Comment: I did a clean install of the apache 2.2, PHP 5.2.11 and still running into this issue. Anyone have any ideas or things I can try?

Comment: Can you provide some code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a lot of pain the problem was the version of the paypalewp I was using... it was an original version. I found a link in the paypal forums to a newer version updated by one of their developers... that version solved all the issues... here is the link to the code.

http://www.pdncommunity.com/pdn/attachments/pdn/ewp/159/1/ewp.php

here is a link to the forum post

http://www.pdncommunity.com/pdn/board/message?board.id=ewp&message.id=87#M87

Comment: You were using different versions of the library on the server and dev machines? or was this an issue with the library that didn't work well with something on your dev machine (like windows, for instance) ?

Comment: The issue was with the library on windows. I had the same version on dev and stage. Worked on linux, didn't work on my windows machine... I upgraded the library to the one mentioned and everything started working.